# How is appsettings.json loaded in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, appsettings

The NET Core 2.x Web API project template provides a `Program.cs` and `Startup.cs` (among other things by default).

If you put a breakpoint inside the constructor of `Startup`, and add a watch you can see the values loaded from `appsettings.json`.

[image]

`Startup.cs` and `Program.cs` are not explicitly loading `appsettings.json`, so it must be happening in the call to `CreateDefaultBuilder` or `Build` in `Program`.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

I have looked the Microsoft source code on https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration and https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting, in particular the [WebHostBuilder](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/1f5379e38d201d329e28b50ecd080e999d274678/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/WebHostBuilder.cs), but I can't see where it happens.

Where is the code that loads the `appsettings.json`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`appsettings.json` is loaded by the call to `CreateDefaultBuilder` located in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebHost.`

```
 //snip
 config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
 //snip
```

Source code available on GitHub - https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/DefaultBuilder/src/WebHost.cs#L165